# Hough transformation calculation

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, hough-transform, straight-line-detection

hough transformation using the normal equation of a line.

For calculating the value of **r** while keeping the values of **x** and **y** same for different **θ** the following formula is used.

**r = sin(θ)y + cos(θ)x**

But the results are not the same as shown in the slides. Am I missing something? I am a newbie please be gentle.

[image]
[image: hough transformation]

Comment: Most libraries/softwares by default expect the angles to be expressed in radians. Have you tried `sin(theta*pi/180)`? Second, for the future, please don't just say "they're different". It doesn't give much info to work on. Instead, share your result and describe the differences.

Comment: What are our results?

Comment: @Ash Thankyou. The angle needs to be expressed in radians.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Ash explained in the comment section above the angles are expected to be expressed in radians not degree.

So `r = sin(θ*pi/180)y + cos(θ*pi/180)x` will give the correct answer.